# How do I start Tor Browser?

Tags: 14.04, tor, tor-browser

My experience with Linux based operative systems are quite small but I learnt a lot when I used Elementary OS Luna (based on Ubuntu 12.04). Had help from internet and a friend with more than 10 years Linux experience (I can't get in touch with him at the moment).

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu) and the installation went without any problems at all.

I have a feeling that the only thing I have done is to have been "preparing" the computer to set up Firefox and other applications to run through Tor instead of installing Tor Browser, please say it's not so?

Otherwise, how do I open Tor Browser?

Comment: @karel he has installed it. He wants to open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you may want to do instead is just download the tor browser bundle (32 or 64) from here: https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en

After it's downloaded, extract it to a folder - it can be in your home directory.

To run it, `cd` to where the you extracted the bundle and run `./start-tor-browser`. This will launch the proxy which then launches the browser.

Comment: It sounds familiar, I think I did something similar on Elementary OS only I used a bash-file to start it with. I will try your suggestion!

Comment: The `start-tor-browser` file is effectively the same idea. It's what would get run if you say had a desktop shortcut to launch the program.

Comment: I actually only had to download the _tor-browser-linux64-4.5.1_en-US.tar.xz_, extract it and place the folder inside in /Downloads then run Tor Browser Setup and suddenly that file became "Tor Browser" which now works just like it would on Windows.
So I added it to the launcher.
**Thanks a bunch!** _I wonder why I had to do everything via the terminal last time on Elementary OS._

Comment: That sounds like a new development - a nice one also. Good to hear.

Answer (score 3):

Tor Browser (*torbrowser-launcher*) is available in the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. torbrowser-launcher handles downloading the most recent version of Tor Browser Bundle for you, in your language and for your architecture. After installing Tor Browser, it can be launched by searching for *tor* in the Dash and clicking the Tor Browser icon. The Tor Browser Launcher Settings app is also installed along with Tor Browser.

[image: Tor]

---

Unfortunately the Tor Browser developers change their signing key that is used to install Tor Browser at periodic intervals which makes the torbrowser-launcher package from the default Ubuntu repositories not work because it is not as up-to-date as the current version of Tor Browser.

These are the instructions from the official [Tor Browser User Manual](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/) in case the Ubuntu torbrowser-launcher package hasn't updated the gpg key that is required to install Tor Browser. When I updated the Tor Browser Developers signing key I noticed that the key that I updated will expire in less than one year.

#### Install Tor Browser

1. Navigate to the Tor Browser [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download).
2. Download the GNU/Linux .tar.xz file
3. (Recommended) Verify the file's signature. The steps for verifying the file's signature are shown below.
4. When the download is complete, extract the archive with the command `tar -xf [TB archive]` or with the Archive Manager.
5. Navigate to the newly extracted Tor Browser directory. Right-click on *start-tor-browser.desktop*, open *Properties* and change the permission to *Allow executing file as program* by clicking the checkbox.
6. Start Tor Browser from the command line by running:

   ```
    ./start-tor-browser
   ```

---

#### Set a keyboard shortcut to start Tor Browser

Remember the location where you downloaded the tor-browser-linux64-xx.x.xx_xx-xx.tar.xz archive. In this example I will call this location `/home/your-username/Downloads/` which is the default location of the Downloads directory in Ubuntu if you replace `your-username` by your own user name.

Remember the directory where you extracted the Tor Browser files. In this example I will call this directory `/home/your-username/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/` where en is the abbreviation for the language and US is the abbreviation for the nation which could be different depending on your language and nation.

Go to Settings -> *Keyboard* -> *View and Customize Shortcuts* -> *Set Custom Shortcut*.

- In the field after Name type *Tor Browser*.
- In the field after Command type: `sh -c '"/home/your-username/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/your-username/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k`
- In order to fill in an entry in the field after Shortcut press any easy to remember keyboard shortcut combination (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>B</kbd>).

[image]

Now you can start Tor Browser by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>B</kbd>.

---

#### How to verify Tor Browser's signature

**Fetching the Tor Developers key**

The Tor Browser team signs Tor Browser releases. Import the Tor Browser Developers signing key (0xEF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290):

```
gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org
```

This should show you something like:

```
gpg: key 4E2C6E8793298290: public key "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
pub   rsa4096 2014-12-15 [C] [expires: 2020-08-24]
      EF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290
uid           [ unknown] Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>
sub   rsa4096 2018-05-26 [S] [expires: 2020-09-12]
```

After importing the key, you can save it to a file (identifying it by fingerprint here):

```
gpg --output ./tor.keyring --export 0xEF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290
```

**Verifying the signature**

To verify the signature of the package you downloaded, you will need to download the corresponding ".asc" signature file as well as the installer file itself, and verify it with a command that asks GnuPG to verify the file that you downloaded.

The example below assumes that you downloaded these two files to your Downloads folder.

```
gpgv --keyring ./tor.keyring ~/Downloads/tor-browser-linux64-9.0_en-US.tar.xz{.asc,}
```

The result of the command should produce something like this:

```
gpgv: Signature made 07/08/19 04:03:49 Pacific Daylight Time
gpgv:                using RSA key EB774491D9FF06E2
gpgv: Good signature from "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify that only this command will run in `/Browser` on 20.04.2LTS:

From ~/Path-To-Extracted-Folder/tor-browser_en-US

```
cd Browser

./start-tor-browser
```

and the browser config dialog will open.